# NestJS tcp microservice load balance

Tags: microservices, nestjs, load-balancing, nestjs-gateways

I have a nestjs app as follows:

1. Gateway - HTTP
2. Microservice1 - TCP (ms1)
3. Microservice2 - TCP (ms2)

Gateway calling ms1 and ms2.
ms1 and ms2 are the same duplicated microservice.

I would like to load the balance between ms1 and ms2.
How do accomplish that in nestjs?

Thanks

Comment: Where will you run your microservices? Many platforms have a built-in load balancer.

Comment: Hi, with kubernetes

Comment: So what have u decided?

Im just faced with a similar situation, and to me TCP is just hardly scalable.

But im curios on what uve decided, coz im facing a similar situaatiion at work, i'd rather use pub/sub, amqp, kafka or any pub/sub system for microservice communication. But due to team's experience may have to go with TCP

Answer (score 0):

Many cloud platforms have a built-in load balancer and I recommend using them. There is a fundamental problem with this TCP story from my point of view. I think that a load balancer could not distribute the TCP packets correctly because it would not know which packets belong together as a logical unit.

Since the NestJS documentation says: "... a microservice is fundamentally an application that uses a different transport layer than HTTP", you could simply create a new Nest application that runs separately but is still accessible via HTTP, because the difference is only in the transport protocol and the cloud built-in load balancer can handle HTTP in any case.

That mean:

1. Gateway - HTTP
2. Microservice-a (n instances) - HTTP

Communication goes via the HttpModule:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  findAll(): Observable<AxiosResponse<Entity[]>> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://host-ms-a:port/my-entities');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is way i asked in the first place, because i want to use the NestJS microservices via TCP (or any other protocol available in NestJS)  and not HTTP. I want to figure out how to use 2 (or n) microservices (duplicated) with LB on top of them in kubernetes env.